# How to use Cognos report studio creating a list with dynamic columns?

Tags: cognos

I need to create a table list in cognos, but the columns of this table would change depend on the data.I don't know how to do this. I just know in cognos report studio, we can drag data into cognos list report.

Update:
I don't know how many columns in this table.Because different data generate different number of columns.Actually,one row of data is a tree hierarchy.For example,the first columns is root,the second column is its child,and maybe the third columns is second child,or first grandson,and so on.So the columns always change.

Answer (score 1):

In report studio just make list report by dragging on your wish.
But make sure it contains all columns that you need (i mean columns inculded in dynamic changes).

Say 4 columns you need at max.

```
Name
Roll no
Age
Address
```

Then create conditional style vairable (You can find in center bar)

now based on this condition dynamically chose the style.

Eg: If condition 1 satisfied

```
Name
Roll No
```

If condition 2 satisfied

```
Name
Address
```

Comment: Thanks.But my situation is different. Please see my updated question.

Comment: ok actually what is your requirement and actual scenario?. 
Because you donno number of columns in table?
 do you have any prompt page or any pages before this final page?

Comment: no prompt page.The data behind the report is dynamic,so the columns always change.

Comment: you mean columns in table changes dynamically a?

Comment: No i guess its not possible in cognos. Because once no of columns in table is changed it will be reflected in report package once it is republished again.
If you want to republish you need Framework Manager, If you go for that option you are about to rebuild whole report.
So according to my knowledge this s impossible.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a Crosstab instead of a List. The columns are created dynamically without any other programming involved.

Just drag a Crosstab into report page, set the columns and rows (which can be nested by the way) and finally, drag the fact field right at the center of the Crosstab.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

1. Create a list as per the requirement.
2. Hide the columns.
3. In each column expression, give the condition and set show as per the condition.